# SQL Server 2000 "yield return" result behavior

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a very long query for our SQL Server 2000 database, and I am returning the results for further processing by my C# application.

Consider this query:

```
declare @sn varchar(20)

select distinct serial_number 
from manufacturingData 
where '7/19/2012'<date_time
order by serial_number

while (0 < (select count(serial_number) from #sn)) begin
  select top 1 @sn=serial_number from #sn
  exec sp_GetSnData @sn
  delete from #sn where serial_number=@sn
end
drop table #sn
```

I am writing this query on `07/19/2012`, so it is only returning records from today.

The query above (for half of today), returned 119 distinct serial numbers and took 52 seconds to execute with the while loop that accompanies it.

Typically, this report is executed for a 30-day period, and there are around 3500 part numbers.

Is there a way to "hook into" the result set so that I can have access to the results as they are generated?

The way it is now, no one knows if the query is going to take 2 minutes or 2 days ...or if it is even still doing anything! Does the manager shut down his computer and go home for the day or is this report query just about done?

Once the individual tables are returned, then I need to process each table individually.

It would be nice if I could

- find out how many distinct items were returned,
- what item is currently being queried, and
- have the resulting table available to process while waiting for the next table to come in.

Is this possible?

FYI: I currently do this in my Windows Form, by sending individual requests to our Server, but this is bogging the Server down and using up all of the available connections.

Comment: Where is the time going? The select distinct to populate the temp table or in executing the stored proc? Certainly a cursor would be more efficient than the temp table and while loop, but not that much more...

Comment: Select Distinct only takes seconds. The stored procedure is what eats up all the time.

Comment: A [DTS package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx) could be used to execute your existing loop and queue a message or send an email on each iteration. You could combine this with a staging table for the results to achieve your three bullet points, though this seems like an inelegant and potentially fragile solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well based on your comments I'd be tring to optimise the stored proc.

But if you just want to give some quick and simple indication of how long it will take

just do

```
select Count(distinct serial_number)  from manufacturingData  where '7/19/2012'< date_time
```

and multiply it by some fiddle factor say .5 second based on your rough performance figures.

If you want progress, then have a look at sql server DMO
Basically you put a Print Statement inside your loop "Processing 1 of 119 say". SMO will pick up the output and trigger an event, you add a handler to drive a say a progress bar.

Note DMO works with 2000, and you can get a backwards compatibility pack so it will work with 2005 and 2008. It does (at the moment also work with 2012), but it's not supported and you'd be mad to rely on it continuing to do so. From 2005 DMO was replaced with SMO.

Me I'd be working on optimsising the sp first though for any quick wins.

Comment: DMO. That's a new one. I'll have to look that up. Get Distinct Serial Numbers takes like 0 seconds, but the stored procedure will take about 2 seconds per number supplied to it. The problem is not the stored procedure, but the data table that was created with data from an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: After Googling **SQL Server 2000 Distributed Management Objects** and reading a couple of links ([here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-sql-dmo) and [here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/database-development/sql-dmo-learning-the-basics)), it appears that DMO is what I would need. Hence, this answers my question.

Comment: Glad to help. Careful how you write it, try and keep all the DMO stuff in one place, that way if you upgrade past 2000, swapping over to SMO won't be too much of a hit.

Answer (score 2):

This is case where you do not want to use the stored proc but write set-based code instead. Code reuse is often a bad thing when you go from processing one record to processing many.

Or revise the proc so that you can send in a comma delimited list and parse it out into a temp table and the do the work. Not knowing what the proc does, I ti shard to suggest actual code to do this. Then it can handle bot single input and multiple input parameters.

BTW you should not name procs with the sp_ prefix as it will look for them first in thesystem procs and then in the user procs so you take a performance hit (albeit small indivudally, over a whole system it can add up) with every single run of every proc and if a system proc ends up with the same name it will use that and not yours.

Comment: I've already looked into doing what you described with the table idea, but that will take a long time to develop. On another note, what should a stored procedure start with, so that a person (developer) readily understands it is a stored procedure? Is there a best practices for that?

Comment: A lot of people use USP_, standing for UserStoredProcedure